# The average length of strings in finite free set

Tags: average, bit-strings

A finite set $S$ of binary strings is called free if no string is a prefix of other string in $S$. I need to show that the average length of string in $S$ is **at least** $\log n$, where $n$ is the number of string in $S$. 
For example, $S=(01,101,111)$ is free, $S'=(01,011)$ isn't free, because $01$ is prefix of $011$.
Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: If $S$ consists only of a string of length $1$, then the average string length is $1\neq \log 1$. Did you mean something slightly different?

Comment: Sorry, I should demand that average length is at least $\log n$, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

SKETCH: Let $n=|S|$, and let the lengths of the words in $S$ be $\ell_1,\ldots,\ell_n$. Then

$$\sum_{k=1}^n2^{-\ell_k}\le 1\tag{1}$$

by the [Kraft-McMillan inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kraft%E2%80%93McMillan_inequality). $(1)$ implies that

$$\frac{n}{\frac1{2^{\ell_1}}+\frac1{2^{\ell_2}}+\ldots+\frac1{2^{\ell_n}}}\ge n\;,\tag{2}$$

where the lefthand side of $(2)$ is the harmonic mean of the numbers $2^{\ell_1},\ldots,2^{\ell_n}$. To complete the argument, just use the [fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean#Relationship_with_other_means) that the harmonic mean of a set of positive real numbers is less than or equal to the geometric mean of those numbers.

Comment: Neat proof! Thanks Brian!

Comment: @enemypower4: You’re welcome!